# How to check if a data is poisson sampled?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, assumptions, poisson-process, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I was reading one article which develops a theory for the Poisson sampled data. That is the data is collected over time-points $\{T_k, k>1\}$, which are jump-moments of a homogeneous Poisson process $\{N(t), t>0\}$.

My question is: if I have a dataset collected over irregular time-points, how do I check that it is Poisson sampled?

Comment: Interarrival times between Poisson events are exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [the comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402993/how-to-check-if-a-data-is-poisson-sampled#comment754009_402993):

Extract the time intervals $x_k=(T_k-T_{k-1})$ for $k=1,\ldots,N$, since the intervals between events in a Poisson process are distributed according to some exponential distribution $Exp(\lambda)$.

Calculate the mean $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Nx_k$ and set $\lambda=1/\bar{x}$, since the expected value of an exponential distribution $Exp(\lambda)$ is $1/\lambda$.

Now you could calculate the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic $D_N=\sup_{x\geq0}|F_N(x)-F(x)|$, where $F(x)=1-\exp(-\lambda x)$ is the distribution function of the exponential distribution, and $F_N(x)=\frac{1}{N}\cdot\#\lbrace x_k \leq x\rbrace$ and assess how well your empirical distribution $F_N$ fits the exponential distribution $F$.

Unfortunately, you estimated the parameter $\lambda$ (better: $\hat{\lambda}$) from the data itself... It has been shown that assessing the significance with the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test directly is [not valid anymore](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2283748) in this case, but improved tables are available (the test is now called Lilliefors test for an exponential distribution with unknown mean). You could also use the package [KScorrect in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KScorrect/index.html).